# How to get INotifyPropertyChanged binding to change when it is bound to a getter property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inotifypropertychanged

I have a vm like this

```
class Vm : Notifiable
{
    public string Name 
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { _Name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }
    private _Name = "";
}
```

And another like this

```
class CollectionVm : Notifiable
{
    public ObservableCollection<Vm> Vms {get;set;}
    public Vm Selected 
    {
        get { return _Selected; }
        set { _Selected= value; OnPropertyChanged("Selected"); }
    }
    Vm _Selected = null;
}
```

And a third like this

```
class OuterVm : Notifiable
{
    CollectionVm _collection;
    public Vm Display
    {
        get {return _collection.Selected; }
    }
}
```

And a binding like this

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding Display.Name}/>
```

My problem is that the textblock doesn't update when the selection changes in the collection. How can I get it to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would require a mechanism by which you raise the `PropertyChanged` event in `OuterVm`.

One simple option would be to just subscribe to the events and pass them through:

```
class OuterVm : Notifiable
{
    public OuterVm()
    {
        // initialize _collection
        _collection.PropertyChanged += (o,e) =>
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == "Selected")
                OnPropertyChanged("Display");
        };
    }
    CollectionVm _collection;
    public Vm Display
    {
        get {return _collection.Selected; }
    }
}
```